# Создание анимированного вложенного списка

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как (какими средствами?) можно реализовать такой вложенный список:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда мы нажимаем на список 3, слева на право появляется развернутый список 3 с его вложениями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно свайпом убирать список или, нажав на другой список, это анимировано скрылся и появился нажатый раскрытый список. Элементы списка так же должны быть вложенными списками и открываться по такому же принципу.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: Лично я в таких случаях пользовался Expandable Recyclerview
Конкретно этим https://github.com/grennis/ExpandableRecyclerView
Не уверен только, что можно реализовать идею со свайпом. Да и раскрывался список сразу под заголовком. В дизайнерские подробности не вдавался.

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше изучать вопрос.